# How to pass props to reducer? ReactJs and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling with react-redux thing quite a lot of hours. I want to show to user `<Alert />` when `isVisible` value is true. I'm still don't understand well architecture of redux. So, I'm trying to pass value to reducer but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Alert component:

```
export default () => {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-warning">
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Indicates a warning that might need attention.
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Weather container:

```
    renderWeather(cityData) {
        const name = cityData.city.name;
        const temps = _.map(cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp), (temp) => temp - 273);

    return (
        <tr key={name}>
            <td><Chart data={temps} color="orange" units="C" /></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
}
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.isVisible ? null : <Alert /> }
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Temperature (C)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ weather, isVisible }) {
    return { weather, isVisible };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Index reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer,
  isVisible: WeatherReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Reducer:

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
        return [...state, action.payload];
    case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
        return {state, isVisible: false}
    }
    return state;
}
```

Action:

```
export function fetchWeather (city) {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;

    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(url);
        .then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: data});
        })
        .catch((error) => { 
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR, payload: error});
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split code into smaller reducers:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: weatherReducer,
  isVisible: isVisibleReducer
});

export default rootReducer;


// reducers:
const weatherReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === FETCH_WEATHER) {
        return action.payload; // data object
    }
    if (action.type === FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR) {
        return action.payload; // error object
    }
    return state;
};

const isVisibleReducer = (state = false, action) => {
    if (action.type === FETCH_WEATHER) {
        return true;
    }
    if (action.type === FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR) {
        return false;
    }
    return state;
};

export { weatherReducer, isVisibleReducer };
```

Now each reducer function has own zone of control.

In your reducer you have mixed type of state. Default is an empty array `[]`, but later you have returned an object (`{state, isVisible: false}`). Don't do that. 
You also reduce `weather` and `isVisible` nodes of state by the same `WeatherReducer`. It's not correct, because the logic of modifying this nodes is different.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide if your state need to be an array or an object. From your reducer, initial state is an empty array, but if `FETCH_WEATHER` is dispatched it returns array and `FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR` returns object.

I suggest you modify combineReducers as well, there is no point passing same reducer to different properties in root state.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 weather: WeatherReducer,
});
```

is enough. Lets assume your state is an Object, with `isVisible` and `weather` properties. So your reducer will become.

```
export default function (state = {isVisible:false, weather:[]}, action) 
 {
  switch (action.type) {
   case FETCH_WEATHER:
     return Object.assign({}, {weather: action.payload, isVisible:false})
   case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
     return Object.assign({}, {weather:null, isVisible:true})
   }
   return state;
 }
```

And finally if you want to show  when isVisible is true you have to

`{this.props.isVisible ? <Alert /> : null }`

Comment: Makes sense, but when I did it is a `this.props.weather.map is not a function` error in console

Comment: I changed initialValue in reducer such that weather will be an empty array instead of empty object. Now it should work unless you are dispatching SET_WEATHER with a  non-array payload,

Comment: Still 'this.props.weather.map is not a function'. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: That will never happen. this.props.weather will either be an empty array or weather array. Try console logging it `this.props.weather` make sure it is an array in all invokations of render, in case it is null in some cases you have to handle null case before doing this.props.weather.map

Comment: @NicyAnto you will have state like this: `{ weather: { weather: [ ... ], isVisible } }`

Comment: @ArkadiyAfonin please note the de-structuring of state in mapStateToProps `mapStateToProps({ weather, isVisible })`

Comment: @NicyAnto yeah, but anyway state will be like i said. it's little bit confusing to look at the state like that :) look at my varian of state in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062288/2795159

Answer (score 0):

you need an Action that will change the isVisible
eq

```
function changeVisible() {
 return {
   type: FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR
  }
}
```

and

```
case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
   return {...state, isVisible: true}
```

Comment: I edited my post. Look, I have exactly the same what you suggested and it doesn't work

Comment: misprint ...state

Comment: and {this.props.isVisible && <Alert /> }

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.weather.map is not a function" so when I add it whole code is crashed

Comment: return [...state, action.payload] - there must be not an array but an object - return {...state, action.payload}

Comment: weather: action.payload

Answer (score 0):

`{this.props.isVisible ? null : <Alert /> }` should be replace by  `{this.props.isVisible ? <Alert /> : null  }` because when **this.props.isVisible** is **true** then only  will be visible but you are doing it wrong..
Hoped it helped

Comment: Nope. I have an error in console "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.weather.map is not a function", so its something wrong with pass value to reducer I think

Comment: Have  you define this.renderWeather in your code?? And remember it must return array